# Cant create FormData object

Tags: javascript, object, form-data, xmlhttprequest-level2

I tried to create the form data
But i can't

```
if(window.FormData)
{
    alert("okk");
}
else
{
    alert("not okk");
}
```

It alerts not okk

What i do now?

I have checked the official mdn documentation of the object but found nothing

Comment: What do you want to do? Your browser doesn't support `FormData`. The list of supported browsers is at the bottom of the MDN page

Comment: my browser is in the list

Comment: What is your browser+version?

Comment: i am using updated version of chrome and firefox

Comment: Your code working for me (alert okk) on chrome Version 30.0.1599.69 m

Comment: how is possible , mine is not doing the same, i have the same version, are there any possibility of any other kind of error

Comment: okk it worked somehow now , but i still didn't know why it didn't ran back then, so thnx a lot to every one

Answer (score 0):

add parenthesis :

```
if (window.FormData())
...
```